# Why $1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-...+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n!}\to 1-\frac{1}{e} $

Tags: limits, exponential-function, factorial

$$1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-...+(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n!}$$
$$\to 1-\frac{1}{e} $$ as $$n \to \infty$$

i know $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}=e$, but this is alternating

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that $$e^x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$? If so, you can simply plug $x = -1$. Otherwise, please provide some background such as what you know about representing $e$, $1/e$ or $e^x$ in terms of limits and/or summations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taylor series for $e^x$ is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {x^i}{i!}$  If we evaluate this at $x=-1$ we get $\frac 1e=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^i}{i!}$  From this we get 
$$1-\frac 1e=1-\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac {(-1)^i}{i!}\\
=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac {(-1)^{i-1}}{i!}$$
by canceling the $i=0$ term and negating the rest

Answer (score 1):

Note that  by changing $x$ to $-x$ we have $$ e^{-x} = 1 -x + (-x)^2 /{2!} + (-x)^3 / {3!} +.....$$

Let $x=1$ and you have the result.